# Nativescript plugin "nativescript-camera-plus": Can´t set Picture Size (width and height)

Tags: nativescript

Hello iam developing a nativescript app and im using the "nativescript-camera-plus" plugin (Plugin on Github: https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus), even setting the parameters (width and height) exactly as described in the Option Interfaces section:

`cam.takePicture({ saveToGallery: true, confirm: false, keepAspectRatio: true, width: 1920, height: 1440 });`

...the plugin takes the picture and saves it, taking as reference the screen resolution of the mobile device divided by 2. Example: If the screen resolution is 1920, the plugin divides by 2 and saves the photo in 960. I need it save the photo with the width and height size that I determined in the options (parameters) of the code. Can someone help me?

MY CODE:

```
exports.takePicFromCam = function (args) {
    cam.requestCameraPermissions().then(function () {
        if (!cam) {
            cam = new CameraPlus();
        }
        cam.takePicture({ saveToGallery: true, confirm: false, keepAspectRatio: true, width: 1920, height: 1440 });

    });
}

cam.on(CameraPlus.photoCapturedEvent, function (args) {

    fromAsset(args.data)
        .then(function (res) {
            var preview = topmost().getViewById('testImagePickResult');

            var picture = res;

            var matrix = new android.graphics.Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(180);

            var imagemfinal = android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.android, 0, 0, picture.android.getWidth(), picture.android.getHeight(), matrix, true);

            preview.src = imagemfinal;

            var novonomedafoto = new Date().getTime();

        });

    imagemsource = page.getViewById("testImagePickResult").imageSource;

    const folderDest = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.currentApp();
    const pathDest = fileSystemModule.path.join(folderDest.path, "photos/" + novonomedafoto + ".jpg");
    const saved = imagemsource.saveToFile(pathDest, "jpg");
    if (saved) {
        console.log("Image saved successfully!");
    }

});

exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
```

Comment: Can you share the code how you are accessing the image asset on the `photoCaptured` event.

Comment: @Manoj , Share the code below!

Comment: Please update the question itself, instead of adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin do not write the file with the width & height you proposed but instead it just returns the resized image asset (`data`) that holds the Bitmap with your width & height spec.

```
data.getImageAsync((bitmap, error) => {
  // Use `bitmap` (android.graphics.Bitmap)
});
```